# How to Configure Azure AD Access Token Lifetime with a Microsoft 365 Standard Subscription

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

My company uses Azure AD SSO. The access token is set to 1 hour by default. We'd like to set the access token lifetime to 24 hours.

I see that this can be configured using conditional access: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview Unfortunately, this requires an Azure Premium license or a Microsoft 365 Business Premium license. We are using Microsoft 365 Standard licenses. Previously the "conditional access" functionality was available to 365 standard licenses, but not anymore.

Is it possible to set the access token to 24 hours with the 365 standard license, and if so, how?

Comment: Have you seen this doc?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes

Comment: Using this feature requires an Azure AD Premium P1 license.

Comment: No, you cannot configure the token lifetime using only the Microsoft 365 standard license.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot configure the token lifetime with the Microsoft 365 standard license. You need to have an [Azure AD Premium P1 license](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#license-requirements).

If you want to customize the lifetime of the access token, you can to use powershell to [create a token lifetime policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes), and then assign the policy to the service principal to set the token lifetime.